# CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify analog on Kotlin (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, encryption, base64

Code on JS

```
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(requestContentString);
```

How do I rewrite it to Kotlin?

I write

```
val base64 = Base64.encodeToString(requestContentString.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
```

But the answers are different

Comment: `requestContentString` in the CryptoJS code is a `WordArray`, while in the Kotlin code it's a string. Both become Base64 encoded. The results are different if the `WordArray` isn't equal to `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(requestContentString)`, where `requestContentString` is the string from the Kotlin code. The corresponding Utf8 encoding on the Kotlin side happens implicitly in `toByteArray`, where Utf8 is the default encoding. More precise can be said, if the creation of the `WordArray` is posted as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(**requestContentString**);
```

**requestContentString** is WordAray = CryptoJS.SHA256("String in here")

```
val base64 = Base64.encodeToString(requestContentString.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Now you have string hashed in SHA-256 and encoded on Base64

Same result in kotlin

1. First hash string to SHA-256

```
val bytes = MessageDigest
            .getInstance("SHA-256")
            .digest(input.toByteArray())
```

2. Encode on Base64

```
 val encodedString1 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP)
```